# SQL - Criar tabela temporária imputando valores manualmente

Tags: sql, select, tabela-temporária, with

Estou fazendo uma query na qual quero criar uma tabela temporária com uma única coluna preenchida com registros de 0 a 23 representando cada um dos intervalos de 1 hora do dia, para depois usar essa tabela temporária no comando select que farei dando join com outras tabelas.
Não tenho permissão para criar novas tabelas no banco de dados, posso apenas criar tabelas temporárias em comandos select.

A ideia que tenho seria algo do gênero (mas que não está funcionando):

```
with 
horarios as(
   select (0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23) as hora
)
select
--resto do codigo aqui
from horarios
join --outra tabela que vou utilizar correlacionando com a tabela de horarios
```

Não posso simplesmente pegar uma tabela existente e usar `select distinct hora` porque mesmo que um horario nao apareça nessa tabela, preciso ter ele no meu resultado final, ou seja, preciso ter todas as 24 horas.

Estou utilizando Amazon Redshift.

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Comment: Você está utilizando qual banco de dados (e versão)?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Consegui solucionar o problema utilizando:

```
with
recursive hora_em_hora(numero) as(
    select 0 as numero
    union all
    select numero + 1 as numero from hora_em_hora
    
    where numero < 24
)
select
--resto do codigo aqui
from hora_em_hora
join --outra tabela que vou utilizar correlacionando com a tabela de horarios
```

Answer (score -2):

Olá, não sei se isso ajuda, mas você pode usar a tabela dual para retornar qualquer valor, exemplo:

```
with horarios as(
   select 0 , 1 , 2 , 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23
   from dual
)
select
*
from horarios
```

Nesse caso, ira retornar 24 colunas com as horas, porem para você selecionar um horário especifico precisara dar um nome a cada uma, exemplo:

```
with horarios as(
   select 0 zero, 1 um, 2 dois, ...
   from dual
)
select
horarios.zero
from horarios
```

Nesse caso ira retonar `0`.

Comment: Infelizmente isso não me ajuda porque eu precisava de uma única coluna em que cada linha fosse um horário. Mas consegui solucionar isso, eu postei a solução como uma nova resposta. De qualquer forma, muito obrigado! :)